# Code impact inside click event?

Tags: javascript

```
element.onclick = function() { 
    myFunction(); 
};

function myFunction() {
    // 100, 500 or 1000 lines of code
}
```

**Does and if yes, how does code *inside* the click event impacts the weight of click event?**

PS! Im interested in code impact in event listener *overall*, not just a function like in my example. What if there was 500 lines of code instead of function?

- Does it matter how big is `myFunction()` code?
- Does it get *processed* before click event is triggered?

I **do not** mean the impact on the moment it's pressed but before this: if event is attached to element.

---

Im asking this because I need to attach the same click event to many elements and the code inside is pretty big. Event delegation is not an option in my situation. **An example:**

```
for(i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    //Just for the sake of this example
    var element = document.createElement('div');

    element.onclick = function() { 
        myFunction(); 
    };
}

function myFunction() {
    // 100, 500 or 1000 lines of code
}
```

Based on this example, should I be thinking about or worried about the size of `myFunction()`?

Comment: No more than any other function.

Comment: @PM77-1 Does it get _processed_ before event is triggered? What if there was 500 lines of code inside the event instead of function?

Comment: it should be processed well in advance unless theres an eval.

Comment: @DanielA.White So.. Big code inside the event listener has pretty big performance impact even before event is triggered, especially if there are many identical?

Comment: If it's a viable option try using jQuery  to attach on the click event, this way you will avoid creating multiple function objects for every element
$('element').click(eventHandler) 
and outside the loop  
var eventHandler = function() {
        myFunction();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function will be processed by the JavaScript runtime when it reads in the file. It will be invoked when you call it in the callback. The time for the callback to invoke the function will be no different if the function is 10 lines or 1000 lines.

Edit:
You may notice the execution time of the function change, as the amount of code increases, but invocation shouldn't change. Things that change invocation speed are looking up nested functions in objects: obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.obj5.func() would be slower than a top-level func() definition (shouldn't be drastically different if it is not nested deep in large objects).

Answer (score 0):

First, Javascript is a single threaded ecosystem.

There is a big eventloop which executes one event after another.

In case your onclick takes ages, you might see the prominent "A script is not responding"

The processing happens when you click it.

The "big event loop" reads the click event and calls all your event handlers for it. So the clicking triggers all the click event handlers being processed. (for the elements that are under your click area)

In case your problem is a not responding script, you could try WebWorkers. I never played with those, as it´s rather new.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Regarding your 500 elements with the same click handler... You can only click one item at a time, no?
Maybe try

```
event.stopPropagation();
```